# Alter this JS to disable button rather than hide it

Tags: javascript

I'm using the snippet below to show a button 10 seconds after the page loads. When clicked the action is successfully occurring, and the button disappears for another 10 seconds before appearing again. What I'd like to be able to do is disable the button rather than hide it (the design jumps about a bit otherwise). I'm weak with JS/JQuery and would appreciate some guidance.

```
        <a class="btn blue" id="manualReload" onclick="reloadResponses();">
            <i class="icon-refresh"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Reload Comments
        </a>

        function reloadResponses() {

            $('#responses').load('loadComments.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>');

            manualReload.style.display ='none';

            setTimeout (function(){
                manualReload.style.display ='inline';
            }, 10000);
        }
```

I'm sure it's simple and if the responder wouldn't mind briefly explaining how their example works I'll learn something tonight :)

Thank you kindly,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jquery button can be disabled by

```
$("#manualReload").prop("disabled",true);
```

but in your case manualReload is not a button. its an anchor tag so u have to do some trick.

add a style

```
a.disabled { color:#ddd; }
```

when u want to disable the anchor tag add this

```
$('#manualReload').addClass('disabled');
```

then in your reloadResponses function run a check first

```
if ($('#manualReload').hasClass('disabled')) return;
```

and after 10 seconds dont forget to remove the class to enable the anchor tag

```
$('#manualReload').removeClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks Vibin, makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
manualReload.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Not working for me (had already tried this), but thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible that it's because it's a hyperlink and not a button? Or does this not matter?

Comment: Disabling only works for input-type elements, so it won't work on an anchor element.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, and I guess we've both learnt something Linuxios :')